# Debian 7.5 Wine аудио

Tags: аудио, debian, wine

Поставил себе вчера Debian, все пока идет нормально. Решил запустить игрушку, виндовую, ввел в консолько, все сразу запустилось но звук скрепит ли, трещит ли, зашел в настройки Wine, потыкался там, при нажатие Проверка звука, получаю тот же скрип. Как я понимаю драйвер на самом дебе pulseaudio, в вайне указано, драйвер: winealso.drv в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

удали пульсаудио совсем. через aptitude, через purge. от него не должно остааться ничего. тогда будет одна alsa (должна быть. если нет - установи) и не будет проблем

Comment: У меня Gnome3